# Why aren't my UITextField Delegate methods being called?

Tags: xcode, swift4

I am simply trying to detect when users begin entering text inside my UITextField.I have read several post on here that instructs me to link my UITextField and then set my textfield delegate, then finally implementing the necessary methods. I have done all that but upon launching my code nothing is displayed. Some assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        button.isEnabled = false
        textField.delegate = self






    }


    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        print("TextField did begin editing method called")
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        print("TextField did end editing method called\(textField.text)")
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        print("TextField should begin editing method called")
        return true;
    }

    func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        print("TextField should clear method called")
        return true;
    }

    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("TextField should end editing method called")
        return true;
    }


    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        print("While entering the characters this method gets called")
        return true;
    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        print("TextField should return method called")
        textField.resignFirstResponder();
        return true;
    }




}
```

Comment: Because they all have the wrong signature. Let Xcode to code completion for you so you get the correct signature.

Comment: Please make sure that the user interaction of your textfield is enabled in the main storyboard.

Comment: deprecated signature, remove methods and write latest one.

Answer (score 1):

As [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) already mentioned your methods have wrong signature. I think you get warnings like **"Instance method 'textFieldDidEndEditing(textField:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'textFieldDidEndEditing' of protocol 'UITextFieldDelegate'"**. You should have the following methods (Swift 4/Xcode 10.3):

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    print("TextField did begin editing method called")
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    print("TextField did end editing method called\(textField.text)")
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    print("TextField should begin editing method called")
    return true;
}

func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    print("TextField should clear method called")
    return true;
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("TextField should end editing method called")
    return true;
}


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    print("While entering the characters this method gets called")
    return true;
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    print("TextField should return method called")
    textField.resignFirstResponder();
    return true;
}
```